# What Django package for customizable template driven data forms application?

Tags: django, package

***** I'm aware some of my terminology is also in the Django dictionary. None of what I write here is intending to use the Django meaning (templates, for example) *****

I am developing an application in Django that will be a customizable template driven data forms application (a project estimation tool that will allow a set of templates to be created and customized based on the type of project).

I want the application to provide a template editor, then regular users will estimate their work for the project/release by starting off from these templates. The templates would be quite simple;  Maybe a dozen or so templates, each with categories and between 2 and 10 line items (tasks) per category where the users would enter their estimation information (hours, description, etc).  It would also be great if the users were able to add custom fields for a unique feature that isn't part of the standard template.

I know how to make a rudimentary version of this from scratch fairly quickly, but given how many Django packages are out there, I figured there may be something to help me.

so, do you know of any packages that would help facilitate this or provide me a solid foundation for my project?

Thanks!

BW

Comment: Look on [bootstraps section](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/bootstraps/) of djangopackages.com. It's a catalogue of all django packages.

Comment: I will, but I don't know what I'm searching for... Keyword suggestions please? I've spent a few hours looking through there but cant identify if something meets my needs.

Comment: Like [Jetstrap](http://jetstrap.com)?